# Online booking system architecture?

Tags: architecture, system

I am an IT student. I have following architecture related question.

"Design a holiday booking system. Customers should be able to book hotel rooms online for holidays by giving dates and destination (country, city, hotel).

Customers must pay by credit card to make a booking (Use  is a separate third party payment gateway for this).

The system should be extend-able in future to include flight and travel bookings.

Much other details were provided.(<==This part we have to assume)"

Question is not very informative, I know. But we can assume anything not clear.

Can it be done with client server architectural pattern? Can you suggest a suitable architectural pattern for this? Specially to provide extend-ability?(Very much appreciated if you can provide some useful article on this) Need to identify what system aspects I should consider when designing such a system. (I know security and scalability, any other non functional requirements?) Also I need to identify the missing information that could be critical in designing the system. 
If you can point out some resource I could use that is most appreciated.

Comment: Good questions, but far too broad for SO. What have you tried so far, any concepts already available? Btw: if this homework please add the homework tag!

Comment: :D totally homework

Answer (score -3):

since booking would be shopping following link might help you!
http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/online-shopping-example.html

Found another one to do this with webservices but dosent hv uml :)

http://www.w3.org/2002/06/ws-example